# Scaffold MVC - Multiple Models per View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use scaffold my models. 
My Model looks like this

```
 public class Patient
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual int MRN { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; } 

    }
public class Issue
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int PatientId { get; set; }
        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
        public virtual string Room { get; set; }
        public virtual string Comment { get; set; }


    }
```

So I would like it to be when the user adds a patient then the Create Scaffold would show the fields for the Patient and also for the Issue. What I am getting now is just the Patient fields. Is there a way to go about this?

I would like to give the option when creating a new patient, the customer gets the ability to add multiple Issues for the patient.

Answer (score 0):

the default scaffolding stuff in MVC3, and even 4, to my knowledge will not handle this.  there are too many different and complex variables for scaffolding to really be reliable in my opinion.  you'll need to wire this up yourself.  i would suggest [creating an editor for your types](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/).  that will simplify things at least a little bit.